# Probability that uniformly distributed points in a square region form a cluster

Tags: probability, expected-value, markov-process, distance

I have a known number of points N uniformly distributed in a square and I want to solve the expected number of clusters of points.

I cluster is formed by a growing algorithm. Starting at a point p, we add to the cluster all the points whose distance to d is lower than a threshold T. Then we repeat this process with all the points that we recently added to the cluster until there are no points whose distance to the ones in the cluster is lower than T. In order to consider that a group of points is a cluster we must have at least 3 of them.

Let $N$ be a random variable that denotes the number of clusters. It can take values from 0 to $int(n_{points}/3)$, where $n_{points}$ is the total number of points in the square area. Then the value I need is:
$$ E[N] = \sum n*p(N=n)$$
where n is the number of clusters. 
I don't know how to solve $p(N=n)$, can anybody help me?

Thank you!

Comment: The recursive definition of cluster suggests a Markov model.

Comment: @Barry The definition need not be recursive: in the graph whose vertices are the $n$ points connected by edges only when their distances are less than $T$, $N$ is the number of connected components containing three or more vertices.  How exactly would one apply a Markov model to this?  (I can see how to apply your idea to make an asymptotic approximation when most clusters are tiny, which occurs when $T\ll (\pi N)^{-1/2}$, but for larger values of $T$ it looks like one would have to track the areas of the $T$-buffers of the clusters, which seems impossible.)

Comment: @whuber Actually T is usually larger than $(\pi N)^{-1/2}$ Any suggestions in that case? Thanks a lot!